# Regex for certain part of a string

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to use with php to clean a certain part of a string.

For example;

```
$string="an-image-name-300x200.jpg";
```

i want to clean just this part "-300x200" of the string.

I've tried this regex

```
'#\-(.*)\.#'
```

but it matches this part of the string "-image-name-300x200."

possible strings;

```
$string="an-image-name-11300x200.jpg";
$string="an-image-x-name-300x11200.jpg";
$string="an-image-x-name-10x200.png";
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-\d+x\d+`

Explanation:

Matches a literal `-`

Matches `\d`, which is shorthand for `[0-9]`, 1 or more times (`+`)

Matches a literal `x`

Matches `\d`, which is shorthand for `[0-9]`, 1 or more times (`+`)

This will be fooled if the file name has more than one 'dimension-like' part of its file name. To fix this, take only the last match in the file name.

Comment: @user2360754 As a side note, you have to accept the answer which has helped you...:)

Answer (score 0):

`#-[0-9]+x[0-9]+#` as a variant.